# Is it possible to construct the real plane from any line using only one vector on the line?

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

Suppose our space is the plane. Then any line on the plane is a subspace for that plane.

Let's take $\vec v$ has a vector on the line, then the span of $\vec v$ is just the line itself.

My prof made a claim that it is possible by taking two vector $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ on the line, we can get back our plane using a linear combination of the two vectors.

This seems to be impossible, I wonder if he meant two vectors on two lines in the plane.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: You need two **non-colinear** vectors, i.e. two vectors from different lines.

Comment: "any line on the plane is a subspace for that plane." -- Any line *through the origin* is a vector subspace.